# Turn 3 objects into multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have 3 objects which contain information about svg icons (FontAwesome). Every object has the same structure but the `prefix` property has a different value. The object below uses `fab` as the prefix, the second `far` and the third `fas`.

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "prefix": "fab",
    "iconName": "facebook-alt",
    "icon": [
      448,
      512,
      [],
      "f26e",
      "M103.3 344.3c-6.5-14.2-6.9-18.3 7.4-23.1 25.6-8 8 9.2 43.2 49.2h.3v-93.9c1.2-50.2 44-92.2 97.7-92.2 53.9 0 97.7 43.5 97.7 96.8 0 63.4-60.8 113.2-128.5 93.3-10.5-4.2-2.1-31.7"
    ]
  },
  "twitter": {
    "prefix": "fab",
    "iconName": "twitter",
    "icon": [
      448,
      512,
      [],
      "f368",
      "M423.9 255.8L411 413.1c-3.3 40.7-63.9 35.1-60.6-4.9l10-122.5-41.1 2.3c10.1 20.7 15.8 43.9 15.8 68.5 0 41.2-16.1 78.7-42.3 106.5l-39.3-39.3c57.9-63.7 13.1-167.2-74-167.2-25.9 0-49.5"
    ]
  },
  "instagram": {
    "prefix": "fab",
    "iconName": "instagram",
    "icon": [
      640,
      512,
      [],
      "f369",
      "M482.2 372.1C476.5 365.2 250 75 242.3 65.5c-13.7-17.2 0-16.8 19.2-16.9 9.7-.1 106.3-.6 116.5-.6 24.1-.1 28.7.6 38.4 12.8 2.1 2.7 205.1 245.8 207.2 248.3 5.5 6.7 15.2 19.1 7.2"
    ]
  },
}
```

Second object:

```
{
  "arrowUp": {
    "prefix": "far",
    "iconName": "arrow-up",
    "icon": [
      448,
      512,
      [],
      "f26e",
      "M103.3 344.3c-6.5-14.2-6.9-18.3 7.4-23.1 25.6-8 8 9.2 43.2 49.2h.3v-93.9c1.2-50.2 44-92.2 97.7-92.2 53.9 0 97.7 43.5 97.7 96.8 0 63.4-60.8 113.2-128.5 93.3-10.5-4.2-2.1-31.7"
    ]
  },
  "arrowLeft": {
    "prefix": "far",
    "iconName": "arrow-left",
    "icon": [
      448,
      512,
      [],
      "f368",
      "M423.9 255.8L411 413.1c-3.3 40.7-63.9 35.1-60.6-4.9l10-122.5-41.1 2.3c10.1 20.7 15.8 43.9 15.8 68.5 0 41.2-16.1 78.7-42.3 106.5l-39.3-39.3c57.9-63.7 13.1-167.2-74-167.2-25.9 0-49.5"
    ]
  },
  "arrowRight": {
    "prefix": "far",
    "iconName": "arrow-right",
    "icon": [
      640,
      512,
      [],
      "f369",
      "M482.2 372.1C476.5 365.2 250 75 242.3 65.5c-13.7-17.2 0-16.8 19.2-16.9 9.7-.1 106.3-.6 116.5-.6 24.1-.1 28.7.6 38.4 12.8 2.1 2.7 205.1 245.8 207.2 248.3 5.5 6.7 15.2 19.1 7.2"
    ]
  },
}
```

Third object:

```
{
  "carrot": {
    "prefix": "fas",
    "iconName": "carrot",
    "icon": [
      448,
      512,
      [],
      "f26e",
      "M103.3 344.3c-6.5-14.2-6.9-18.3 7.4-23.1 25.6-8 8 9.2 43.2 49.2h.3v-93.9c1.2-50.2 44-92.2 97.7-92.2 53.9 0 97.7 43.5 97.7 96.8 0 63.4-60.8 113.2-128.5 93.3-10.5-4.2-2.1-31.7"
    ]
  },
  "cat": {
    "prefix": "fas",
    "iconName": "cat",
    "icon": [
      448,
      512,
      [],
      "f368",
      "M423.9 255.8L411 413.1c-3.3 40.7-63.9 35.1-60.6-4.9l10-122.5-41.1 2.3c10.1 20.7 15.8 43.9 15.8 68.5 0 41.2-16.1 78.7-42.3 106.5l-39.3-39.3c57.9-63.7 13.1-167.2-74-167.2-25.9 0-49.5"
    ]
  },
  "dog": {
    "prefix": "fas",
    "iconName": "dog",
    "icon": [
      640,
      512,
      [],
      "f369",
      "M482.2 372.1C476.5 365.2 250 75 242.3 65.5c-13.7-17.2 0-16.8 19.2-16.9 9.7-.1 106.3-.6 116.5-.6 24.1-.1 28.7.6 38.4 12.8 2.1 2.7 205.1 245.8 207.2 248.3 5.5 6.7 15.2 19.1 7.2"
    ]
  },
}
```

I am trying to turn the 3 objects seen above into this:

```
"brands": [
  "facebook",
  "twitter",
  "instagram",
],
"regular": [
  "arrow-up",
  "arrow-left",
  "arrow-right",
],
"solid": [
  "carrot",
  "cat",
  "dog",
],
```

The tricky part is also changing the prefix name into another value for the array. `fab` would be brands, `far` regular, and `fas` solid.

I am using React and have Babel. Here's what I have so far...

```
const objects = [
    ...Object.values( fab ),
    ...Object.values( far ),
    ...Object.values( fas ),
]
```

It turns all the objects into arrays but I'm not sure how to get the structure i want.

And for changing the prefix into a name I believe this is a good start... This is just an example for changing `fab` into `brands`

```
//find the index of object from array
const objIndex = objects.findIndex(obj => obj.value === 'fab');

// make new object of updated object   
const updatedObj = { ...objects[objIndex], prefix: 'brands'};

// make new array of objects
const updatedObjects = [
  ...objects.slice(0, objIndex),
  updatedObj,
  ...objects.slice(objIndex + 1),
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for Keys of object which you can easily get from [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
let obj1= {"facebook": { "prefix": "fab", "iconName": "facebook-alt","icon": [ 448, 512, [], "f26e", "M103.3 344.3c-6.5-14.2-6.9-18.3 7.4-23.1 25.6-8 8 9.2 43.2 49.2h.3v-93.9c1.2-50.2 44-92.2 97.7-92.2 53.9 0 97.7 43.5 97.7 96.8 0 63.4-60.8 113.2-128.5 93.3-10.5-4.2-2.1-31.7" ]},"twitter": {"prefix": "fab",    "iconName": "twitter", "icon": [  448,  512, [],   "f368", "M423.9 255.8L411 413.1c-3.3 40.7-63.9 35.1-60.6-4.9l10-122.5-41.1 2.3c10.1 20.7 15.8 43.9 15.8 68.5 0 41.2-16.1 78.7-42.3 106.5l-39.3-39.3c57.9-63.7 13.1-167.2-74-167.2-25.9 0-49.5"  ] },"instagram": {"prefix": "fab","iconName": "instagram", "icon": [ 640, 512, [], "f369","M482.2 372.1C476.5 365.2 250 75 242.3 65.5c-13.7-17.2 0-16.8 19.2-16.9 9.7-.1 106.3-.6 116.5-.6 24.1-.1 28.7.6 38.4 12.8 2.1 2.7 205.1 245.8 207.2 248.3 5.5 6.7 15.2 19.1 7.2"]},}
let obj2={"arrowUp": { "prefix": "far", "iconName": "arrow-up", "icon": [ 448,  512,  [], "f26e", "M103.3 344.3c-6.5-14.2-6.9-18.3 7.4-23.1 25.6-8 8 9.2 43.2 49.2h.3v-93.9c1.2-50.2 44-92.2 97.7-92.2 53.9 0 97.7 43.5 97.7 96.8 0 63.4-60.8 113.2-128.5 93.3-10.5-4.2-2.1-31.7"]},"arrowLeft": { "prefix": "far", "iconName": "arrow-left", "icon": [ 448, 512,[],     "f368", "M423.9 255.8L411 413.1c-3.3 40.7-63.9 35.1-60.6-4.9l10-122.5-41.1 2.3c10.1 20.7 15.8 43.9 15.8 68.5 0 41.2-16.1 78.7-42.3 106.5l-39.3-39.3c57.9-63.7 13.1-167.2-74-167.2-25.9 0-49.5" ]}, "arrowRight": { "prefix": "far", "iconName": "arrow-right", "icon": [  640, 512, [],"f369", "M482.2 372.1C476.5 365.2 250 75 242.3 65.5c-13.7-17.2 0-16.8 19.2-16.9 9.7-.1 106.3-.6 116.5-.6 24.1-.1 28.7.6 38.4 12.8 2.1 2.7 205.1 245.8 207.2 248.3 5.5 6.7 15.2 19.1 7.2"]},}
let obj3 ={"carrot": {"prefix": "fas", "iconName": "carrot","icon": [ 448, 512, [],"f26e","M103.3 344.3c-6.5-14.2-6.9-18.3 7.4-23.1 25.6-8 8 9.2 43.2 49.2h.3v-93.9c1.2-50.2 44-92.2 97.7-92.2 53.9 0 97.7 43.5 97.7 96.8 0 63.4-60.8 113.2-128.5 93.3-10.5-4.2-2.1-31.7"]}, "cat": { "prefix": "fas", "iconName": "cat", "icon": [    448, 512, [],"f368","M423.9 255.8L411 413.1c-3.3 40.7-63.9 35.1-60.6-4.9l10-122.5-41.1 2.3c10.1 20.7 15.8 43.9 15.8 68.5 0 41.2-16.1 78.7-42.3 106.5l-39.3-39.3c57.9-63.7 13.1-167.2-74-167.2-25.9 0-49.5"]}, "dog": { "prefix": "fas", "iconName": "dog", "icon": [     640, 512, [],"f369","M482.2 372.1C476.5 365.2 250 75 242.3 65.5c-13.7-17.2 0-16.8 19.2-16.9 9.7-.1 106.3-.6 116.5-.6 24.1-.1 28.7.6 38.4 12.8 2.1 2.7 205.1 245.8 207.2 248.3 5.5 6.7 15.2 19.1 7.2" ]},}

let op = [
  {'brand': Object.keys(obj1)},
  {'regular': Object.keys(obj2).map(e=> obj2[e].iconName)},
  {'solid':  Object.keys(obj3)}
]

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, I removed the comment. There is another issue however. The code is creating array groups with the object key value, as the array key value. The key of the array has to be the `iconName` value from the object. For example, `{"arrowUp": { "prefix": "far", "iconName": "arrow-up" ...` should turn into `"regular": ["arrow-up", ...` not `"regular": ["arrowUp", ...`

Comment: @CyberJunkie Edited my answer to include the camel-case conversion

Comment: @CyberJunkie you can check the updated one.all you need is just use regex to find the uppercase letter and add `-` and change matched characters to lowercase

Comment: @CodeManiac sorry, I don't think I explained properly. There is no need for camel case conversion. I just want to replace the key value with the value of `iconName` from its array. As a better example, `{"randomNameHere": { "prefix": "far", "iconName": "arrow-up" ...` where I just need to grab the `iconName` value and use it to replace `randomNameHere`. The key name may differ from the iconName so it cannot be converted with regex.

Comment: @CyberJunkie i didn't noticed `iconName`. you can check the updated one

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Added conversion of camel-case to dashes

If the objects are always sectioned out as you posted, could you not just do something like:

```
const convertStrings = (str) => {
  return str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, (g) => `-${g[0].toLowerCase()}`);
};

const objects = {
  "brands": Object.keys(fab).map(convertStrings),
  "regular": Object.keys(far).map(convertStrings),
  "solid": Object.keys(fas).map(convertStrings),
}
```

Which gave me the output:

```
{
  brands: ["facebook", "twitter", "instagram"],
  regular: ["arrow-up", "arrow-left", "arrow-right"],
  solid: ["carrot", "cat", "dog"]
}
```

https://jsbin.com/soxekedepe/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` to get the key names and then map over the values, returning `obj[k].iconName`:

```js
let fab= {"facebook": { "prefix": "fab", "iconName": "facebook-alt","icon": [ 448, 512, [], "f26e", "M103.3 344.3c-6.5-14.2-6.9-18.3 7.4-23.1 25.6-8 8 9.2 43.2 49.2h.3v-93.9c1.2-50.2 44-92.2 97.7-92.2 53.9 0 97.7 43.5 97.7 96.8 0 63.4-60.8 113.2-128.5 93.3-10.5-4.2-2.1-31.7" ]},"twitter": {"prefix": "fab",    "iconName": "twitter", "icon": [  448,  512, [],   "f368", "M423.9 255.8L411 413.1c-3.3 40.7-63.9 35.1-60.6-4.9l10-122.5-41.1 2.3c10.1 20.7 15.8 43.9 15.8 68.5 0 41.2-16.1 78.7-42.3 106.5l-39.3-39.3c57.9-63.7 13.1-167.2-74-167.2-25.9 0-49.5"  ] },"instagram": {"prefix": "fab","iconName": "instagram", "icon": [ 640, 512, [], "f369","M482.2 372.1C476.5 365.2 250 75 242.3 65.5c-13.7-17.2 0-16.8 19.2-16.9 9.7-.1 106.3-.6 116.5-.6 24.1-.1 28.7.6 38.4 12.8 2.1 2.7 205.1 245.8 207.2 248.3 5.5 6.7 15.2 19.1 7.2"]},}
let far={"arrowUp": { "prefix": "far", "iconName": "arrow-up", "icon": [ 448,  512,  [], "f26e", "M103.3 344.3c-6.5-14.2-6.9-18.3 7.4-23.1 25.6-8 8 9.2 43.2 49.2h.3v-93.9c1.2-50.2 44-92.2 97.7-92.2 53.9 0 97.7 43.5 97.7 96.8 0 63.4-60.8 113.2-128.5 93.3-10.5-4.2-2.1-31.7"]},"arrowLeft": { "prefix": "far", "iconName": "arrow-left", "icon": [ 448, 512,[],     "f368", "M423.9 255.8L411 413.1c-3.3 40.7-63.9 35.1-60.6-4.9l10-122.5-41.1 2.3c10.1 20.7 15.8 43.9 15.8 68.5 0 41.2-16.1 78.7-42.3 106.5l-39.3-39.3c57.9-63.7 13.1-167.2-74-167.2-25.9 0-49.5" ]}, "arrowRight": { "prefix": "far", "iconName": "arrow-right", "icon": [  640, 512, [],"f369", "M482.2 372.1C476.5 365.2 250 75 242.3 65.5c-13.7-17.2 0-16.8 19.2-16.9 9.7-.1 106.3-.6 116.5-.6 24.1-.1 28.7.6 38.4 12.8 2.1 2.7 205.1 245.8 207.2 248.3 5.5 6.7 15.2 19.1 7.2"]},}
let fas ={"carrot": {"prefix": "fas", "iconName": "carrot","icon": [ 448, 512, [],"f26e","M103.3 344.3c-6.5-14.2-6.9-18.3 7.4-23.1 25.6-8 8 9.2 43.2 49.2h.3v-93.9c1.2-50.2 44-92.2 97.7-92.2 53.9 0 97.7 43.5 97.7 96.8 0 63.4-60.8 113.2-128.5 93.3-10.5-4.2-2.1-31.7"]}, "cat": { "prefix": "fas", "iconName": "cat", "icon": [    448, 512, [],"f368","M423.9 255.8L411 413.1c-3.3 40.7-63.9 35.1-60.6-4.9l10-122.5-41.1 2.3c10.1 20.7 15.8 43.9 15.8 68.5 0 41.2-16.1 78.7-42.3 106.5l-39.3-39.3c57.9-63.7 13.1-167.2-74-167.2-25.9 0-49.5"]}, "dog": { "prefix": "fas", "iconName": "dog", "icon": [     640, 512, [],"f369","M482.2 372.1C476.5 365.2 250 75 242.3 65.5c-13.7-17.2 0-16.8 19.2-16.9 9.7-.1 106.3-.6 116.5-.6 24.1-.1 28.7.6 38.4 12.8 2.1 2.7 205.1 245.8 207.2 248.3 5.5 6.7 15.2 19.1 7.2" ]},}

let op = [
  {"brands": Object.keys(fab)},
  {"regular": Object.keys(far).map(k => { return far[k].iconName; })},
  {"solid": Object.keys(fas).map(k => { return fas[k].iconName; })}
]

console.log(op)
```